# Using reference (ref) as parameter for objects of the same base class (C#)

Tags: c#, reference, subclass, ref

Is it possible to pass in an object reference to a method signature for classes that share the same base class? i.e., simplified:

```
public class ClassA : System.Web.UI.Control 
public class ClassB : System.Web.UI.Control
```

In Page:

```
private void SetCurrentView(ref Control ctrl)
{
  ctrl.Visible = true;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  aClass = new ClassA();
  bClass = new ClassB();
  SetCurrentView(ref aClass);
  SetCurrentView(ref bClass);
}
```

Obviously, as is, this does not work, and casting it in the method call would not be an assignable reference. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: There is simple way to check it. Just try execute your simplified example.

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood the purpose of `ref`. Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Thank you all. And yes I tried the specified solution (always do before asking), which threw a design error that the address was unassignable (makes sense.) @Jon Skeet - thank you for the article. It's definitely helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you do not need `ref` here anyway.

To set the visibility, the following does exactly what you need:

```
private void SetCurrentView(Control ctrl)
{
  ctrl.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use `ref` in you case. Everything that is not a value type (`char,int`,etc`) will be passed as reference : it means the variable will point the same object in memory so it will affect the same instance

*Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, and definitely helpful for getting the cobwebs out! The first sentence of the second paragraph hit me on the head and woke everything back up in my brain.